# Why is QPdfDocument not found?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

During installation, I selected Additional Libraries "Qt PDF" and "Qt WebEngine". Then I wrote this code in CMake:

```cmake
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Pdf) 
target_link_libraries(mytarget Qt6::Pdf)
```

Then I got the message:

> Found package configuration file: C:/Qt/6.3.1/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/Qt6Config.cmake but it set Qt6_FOUND to FALSE so package "Qt6" is considered to be NOT FOUND.
>
> Reason given by package: Failed to find Qt component "Pdf".
>
> Expected Config file at "C:/Qt/6.3.1/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6Pdf/Qt6PdfConfig.cmake" does NOT exist"

Also, I don't have the `Qt6PdfConfig.cmake` file in my system. Even after installing the program, I can't find it. How can it be downloaded and installed?

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPdfDocument> //not found

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```